# How to read characters from a string inside a for loop in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

Am trying to read some characters from a string inside a for loop, but am not getting the result. My code is like this

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set str="abcdefgh"
for /l %%x in (1,1,5) do (
set fstr=!str:~1,%%x!
echo %fstr%
)
```

All the time am getting the result "Echo is off". kindly help how to solve this

Comment: You need to use `!` when echoing `fstr` too; try `echo !fstr!` instead of `echo %fstr%` within the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
echo %fstr%
```

to

```
echo !fstr!
```

%fstr% shows the value of `fstr` as it existed when the line was PARSED, that is, not set, so

```
ECHO %fstr%
```

is interpreted as

```
echo
```

Hence `ECHO` reports the echo status - `ECHO is off`

```
ECHO !fstr!
```

show the value of `fstr` as it is changed within the loop (The RUN-TIME value).