# not able to read characters of a string inside a for loop

Tags: batch-file

Am trying to read characters of a string inside a for loop.

The command !string:~1,3! works fine. But can I do this with variables instead of 1 and 3. I tried the following code, but I don't know what is wrong. Its not working.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set string=abcdefghij
set /a count=1
for /l %%x in (1,1,3) do (
  set string2=!string:~%count%,1!
  set /a count+=1
  echo !string2!
  pause
)
```

but It always gives the output as:

```
b
```

I want the output to be as:

```
b
c
d
```

Kindly help in solving this.. A big thanks in advance

Comment: If you ask a question and don't receive much attention, don't ask it again.  (Dupe from same user): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15743077/how-to-read-characters-from-a-string-inside-a-for-loop-in-a-batch-file

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve what you want, you need to do a Delayed Expansion *twice*, that is, something like this:

```
set string2=!string:~!count!,1!
```

Of course, previous line is invalid. Although there are several ways to solve this problem, most of they use `call` command that is slow. To fix this problem so it run in the fastest way use a `for` command to change the first !count! expansion into a FOR replaceable parameter, and then use it in the original expression:

```
for %%i in (!count!) do set string2=!string:~%%i,1!
```

Comment: +1 I like this.  It's cleaner than `call`.  You're right about the time difference between your method and `call` as well.  I just made a test script looping from 1 to 1000 using either `for` as you have, or `call` as I did, to set `%count%`.  The `for` method took 331ms.  The `call` method took 1.195 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the expansion of `%count%` isn't delayed, so it has the same value for every loop iteration.  It's better written like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set string=abcdefghij
set /a count=1
for /l %%x in (%count%,1,3) do (
    set string2=!string:~%%x,1!
    echo !string2!
)
```

---

**Edit**

If you want to keep `%count%` evaluated as the variable is set and not just at the beginning of the `for` loop, use [Aacini's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15885934/1683264).

Comment: But is there any way expand %count%? Is it possible to do so? Please explain

Comment: @RaathanaRanganath - see Aacini's answer.